# How do I put slingscold icon on plank?

Tags: 16.04, icons, macbuntu, plank

I installed `slingscold` and `plank` by typing the following in terminal:

```
sudo su
add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/macbuntu
apt update
apt install slingscold
apt install plank
apt install macbuntu-os-plank-theme-lts-v7
```

Now I am able to launch `slingscold` and `plank`. However I cannot figure out how to put the `slingscold` icon on `plank`. Usual methods don't seem to work in case of `slingscold`.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you join me in chat for a sec? https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room

Comment: yes start a chat

Answer (score 8):

Press

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Terminal appears.

Type the following:

```
sudo su
killall plank
```

Open file manager by clicking on it

[image]

Go to View in Menu Bar

[image]

Go to "Show Hidden Files"

[image]

Tick the box left to it

[image]

Click on .config

[image]

Click on plank

[image]

Click on dock1

[image]

Click on launchers

[image]

Go to any text file

[image]

Right click on it and select copy

[image]

Right click on any empty space in the same window and click on paste

[image]

Double click on the newly created file

[image]

Delete the portion between `applications/` and `.desktop`

[image]

Type `slingscold` in it's place.

[image]

Save and close the file

[image]

Close the file manager

[image]

Go to Ubuntu launch icon

[image]

Type plank

[image]

Click on the plank icon that now appears

[image]

Plank now has `slingscold` icon on it

[image]

Click on the icon and enjoy using `slingscold`

[image]

Comment: askubuntu should have more of these answers!!

Answer (score 1):

in alternative you may open the folder below

```
/usr/share/applications
```

where are all the application launchers, search for the Slingcold icon and drag&drop it on plank. It works fine for me and I think it is quite simplier